# Using php to create a button that calls a php function

Tags: php, javascript, html

Currently I have the following but it doesn't like me very much:
1. index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id = "bookList">
    <?php
    include("list.php");
    ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

2. list.php:

```
<?php
echo '<button id = "read">Read</button><br><br>';
echo 
"<script type=\"text/javascript\">
$(\"#read\").click(function()
{
alert(\"<?php display(); ?>\");
});
</script>";

function display()
{
    echo "hello";
}
?>
```

As is hopefully obvious from the code I posted above, I am attempting to create a button using php which when clicked on will in turn call a php function. I have not been successful as of yet. Any advice will be appreciated but I'd like my code to stay as close to what I currently have as possible.

Comment: no not the same at all.

Comment: Yes, very much the same. Read the answer.

Comment: I read it before I posted this question. It didn't help me diddly squat.

Comment: As stated in the other answer, to run any sort of PHP code from HTML/Javascript, you need to make another HTTP request to the server using 1. a link, 2. a form submit or 3. an AJAX request. Have you tried any of these things?

Comment: the button I am creating is the "link" I am trying to use.

Comment: In your case in particular though, you seem to be wanting to use jQuery functions without including jQuery into the page?

Comment: A button by itself is not a link and is not a form; it does not change the page or create an AJAX request.

Comment: index.php is simply an example of a much larger file. How then would I go about making the button create an AJAX request that would allow me to do what I need?

Comment: You can make the button the submit button of a `<form>` or you explicitly fire off an AJAX request using Javascript. Look at the jQuery documentation for how to do the latter.

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, here are the api docs for the [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function...

Comment: That's a great idea(the `<form>` part!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some basic misunderstandings here. PHP and Javascript does not interact like that

Let me give a rather silly analogy:

1. You go to the coffee shop and order some coffee.
2. The shop keeper gives you the coffee. You take a sip and find you need more sugar
3. You tell the shopkeeper who adds the sugar to your coffee. Lets call this action `addSugar()`.

Everything is cool here. Now what happens in this second scenario:

1. You go to the coffee shop and order some coffee.
2. The shop keeper gives you the coffee. You take the coffee with you and walk home
3. You take a sip and find you need more sugar
4. You tell the shopkeeper to `addSugar()`...? erm...

Well the shopkeeper aint there. In the same way, when a page reaches your browser, it has left the coffee shop. There is no PHP/shopkeeper around anymore

Your request to `addSugar()` that you are trying on button click using Javascript will not work.

What you will need to do is use something called `AJAX` which is a way to quickly run to the coffeshop just for adding a little sugar.. Its a broader topic and you will need to read about it, but there are tons of resources out there..

Comment: Haha. Love the analogy...+1

Comment: Cleared up the theory for me really well but how would I go about implementing AJAX to do what I need in this instance?

Comment: Well you could start by checking how to make an ajax call using [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) which is pretty easy to understand.. There are some really easy tutorials out there..